# How to specify to some node receive more replicas of the service in SWARM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have 3 servers, one has more hardware than the others. I have a service that has 25 replicas when I run `docker stack deploy` each server receives the same amount of replicas of that specific server.

Can I specify some kind of percentage of replicas in the dockercompose file to redirect to that specific node?

Answer (score 0):

You can define resource reservations for the containers you run, and docker will avoid scheduling containers are nodes that are out of resources according to those memory and CPU reservations. Note that this should be done for all containers being scheduled, and you'll need to profile your applications to identify an appropriate reservation and limit amount. Keep in mind during heavy load these numbers will increase, and the response to exceeding the memory limit is to kill the container and restart another instance, which would be bad during peak load, so make your limits sufficiently large.

Here's the example from [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources):

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```

See also Docker's resource constraints documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

---

A second less ideal option is to define node labels that split the nodes into equal size groups, where size is based on the resources. Then you can abuse the functionality that allows workload to be distributed across HA zones to split the workload between the machines based on their resources. For that you would use a placement preferences spread policy to spread the workload between different values of a label:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    deploy:
      placement:
        preferences:
          - spread: node.labels.zone
```

Comment: Okay, I understood, but the problem is that when I create the service with 25 replicas, the swarm hasn't yet big processing data. 

In my Swarm I'm running gitlab_runners container that creates a container to receive requests. So it has low processing in the start and creates equally to the nodes the number of replicas. But when the requests of the GitLab comes, my leader machine has more hardware to receive more requests. I wanted to start the swarm with more runners in my leader machine when doesn't started the big processing part.

Comment: @LeonardoCampanha Yes, that would ideally be done by setting a reservation on cpu or memory. Unless I'm misunderstanding your request.